# How do I access my old files from an old Macbook HDD with Lubuntu?

Tags: hard-drive, permission

I wasn't sure if I should put this on the Apple or Linux stack exchange but here's my problem. So my old Macbook died a while back and I realized that it might have had some important information. My main PC now is a Lubuntu Desktop. So what I did was I bought a SATA with an HDD power connecter to USB cord and I plugged the SATA side into the HDD and the USB into my PC. I was able to get into the HDD's files, but when I was getting into the documents file it said that I could not access it due to permissions. So I changed the permissions and when I clicked apply it said "Error setting permissions: Read-only file system". Can someone tell me how to save the information on the HDD while being able to access it?

Comment: Target Disk mode only works with two working Macs. Ender Scythe has no working Macs.

Comment: The computer is **completly dead**.

Comment: Try accessing it as `root`.

Comment: see [this link](http://superuser.com/questions/84446/how-to-mount-a-hfs-partition-in-ubuntu-as-read-write)

Comment: @David Anderson That will only work if I had a working Mac, I have no working Macs.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/332315/how-to-read-and-write-hfs-journaled-external-hdd-in-ubuntu-without-access-to-os & link in first answer. Apparently Lubuntu can't deal with Journalled HFS

Comment: I was referring to this [answer](http://superuser.com/questions/84446/how-to-mount-a-hfs-partition-in-ubuntu-as-read-write/365270#365270).

Answer (score 1):

This is probably due to your FS type and your old disk which is probably HFS+.
You need to add extra packages to read it.

Try this link: https://askubuntu.com/questions/332315/how-to-read-and-write-hfs-journaled-external-hdd-in-ubuntu-without-access-to-os

Here's the copy paste of the answer :

> First, make sure that you have hfsprogs installed. Example installation command:
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get install hfsprogs
> ```
>
> Next, mount or remount the HFS+ drive; commands need to be as follows:
>
> ```
> sudo mount -t hfsplus -o force,rw /dev/sdXY /media/mntpoint
> ```
>
> or
>
> ```
> sudo mount -t hfsplus -o remount,force,rw /mount/point
> ```
>
> Finally, if the drive was improperly unmounted or has otherwise become partially corrupted run fsck.hfsplus ... as such:
>
> ```
> sudo fsck.hfsplus -f /dev/sdXY
> ```